# need to select number between 1 to 10 my code isnt working need help and perhaps a better way to program this

Tags: java

Hello question I need to ask user to input number between 1 to 10 I came up with this code.

To my understaning this will loop the question until the number is between 1-10

so why is not working

also is there a better way to program this because this do while loop is confusing to me

```
do {
       System.out.println("wat voor cijfer heb je voor project fasten your seatbelt?");
       vakCijfers[0] = invoer.nextInt();
} while (vakCijfers[0] <= 1 && vakCijfers[0] >= 10);
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  The likely reason that you are unable to add code is because you are attempting to add far too much of it.  You should show us a [mcve], no more than 15-20 lines, which demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Hint: What number is *both* less than 1 *and* greater than 10?

Answer (score 1):

Do while loops work something like this:

**Do this thing while this statement is true**

Your code is not working because your statement is asking for a number that evaluates to be `<= 1 && >= 10`
You can't have a number that fits your statements description, therefore the statement will always evaluate to **false** meaning the `do while` loop never triggers.

Something like this could make it easier for you to understand:

```
do{
System.out.println("wat voor cijfer heb je voor project fasten your seatbelt?");
int i = 0;
vakCijfers[i] = invoer.nextInt();
i++;
}while(i< 10);
```